# Expectation and Variance of Negative Binomial Distribution from the MGF

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, binomial-distribution, moment-generating-functions

> For any $0<p<1$ and $r$ a positive integer, the probability function
>   $$f(x)={{r+x-1}\choose{x}}p^r(1-p)^x \ \ \ \ \ \ x=0,1,2...$$
>   defines a random variable $X$.

I have computed the mgf of the above distribution to be $$m_X(u)=\Big(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u)}\Big)^r \ \ \ \ \ \ \ u<\text{ln}((1-p)^{-1})$$

> Hence compute $\ \mathbb{E}(X)\ $ and $\ Var(X)$

For the expectation, I realised that 
$$m'_X(0)=\mathbb{E}(X)$$
Deriving the mgf with respect to $u$ and then substituting $u=0$,
$$m'_X(0)=r\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)^{r-1}$$
But this does note equal the correct expectation, which is $\frac{r(1-p)}{p}$.

Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Well, your mgf is okay, but since the expectation should be $ r (1-p)/p$ and the variance $r(1-p)/p^2$..., then yes, you have gone awry somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I have found my mistake. I will update the above text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}\mathsf M'_X(u) & = \dfrac{\mathsf d~~}{\mathsf d u}\left(\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u}\right)^r\\[1ex] & =p^r \dfrac{\mathsf d (1-(1-p)e^u)^{-r}}{\mathsf d u}\\[1ex] &= p^r (1-(1-p)e^u)^{-r-1}(-r)\dfrac{\mathsf d (1-(1-p)e^u)}{\mathsf d u}\\[1ex] &= p^r r(1-(1-p)e^u)^{-r-1}(1-p)e^u\\[2ex] \mathsf M'_X(0) &= rp^{-1}(1-p)\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering, why when I applied the chain rule (i.e. $r(...)^{r-1}$) did this not yield the same answer? Did I use the chain rule incorrectly?

Comment: Did you do the following? $$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathsf d~~}{\mathsf d u}\left(\dfrac{p}{g(u)}\right)^r &= rp^r\left(\dfrac{1}{g(u)}\right)^{r-1}\dfrac{\mathsf d ~~}{\mathsf d u}\dfrac{1}{g(u)}\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{rp^r}{g^{r-1}(u)}\dfrac{-1}{g^2(u)}g'(u)\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{-rp^r ~g'(u)}{g^{r+1}(u)}\\&= -r~p^r~g^{-r-1}(u)~g'(u)\end{align}$$ ... where with $g(u)=(1-(1-p)e^u)$ you obtain the required result.

Comment: Yes, I believe I did. My method was slightly longer and it went like this $$m'_x(u)=r\Big(\frac{g(u)(0)+p(1-p)e^u}{(g(u))^2}\Big)^{r-1}=r\Big(\frac{p(1-p)e^u}{(g(u))^2}\Big)^{r-1}$$. Then substituting $u=0$, $$r\Big(\frac{p(1-p)}{p^2}\Big)^{r-1}=r\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)^{r-1}$$ But this does not seem like the correct result.

Comment: It does not seem the correct method. The chain rule is $[f\circ g]'(x)= f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$  You appear to be trying to make it $f'(g'(x))$ .

Comment: I was trying to apply the quotient rule inside the brackets. In your response, does $f(x)=p$ and $g(x)=(1-(1-p)e^u)$?

Comment: The point is you *don't* apply the quotient rule *inside* the brackets; rather you *chain* the derivatives. (and in the example $f(g)=(g)^r, g(x)=(p/(1-(1-p)e^x)$.)$$\begin{align}\mathcal D_u\left[\left(\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u)}\right)^r\right] &= r\left(\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u)}\right)^{r-1}\times\mathcal D_u\left[\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u)}\right]\\[1ex] &= r\left(\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u)}\right)^{r-1}\times\dfrac{-p \times\mathcal D_u[(1-(1-p)e^u)]}{(1-(1-p)e^u)^2}\\[1ex] &= r\left(\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u)}\right)^{r-1}\times\dfrac{p \times(1-p)e^u}{(1-(1-p)e^u)^2} \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have also posted the third part of this question. Please consider checking it out :)) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830173/show-lim-p-to-0-m-yu-big-frac11-2u-bigr-where-y-2px?noredirect=1#comment5835846_2830173