# Show $\lim_{p\to 0} m_Y(u)=\Big(\frac{1}{1-2u}\Big)^r$ where $Y=2pX$

Tags: limits, statistics, binomial-distribution, moment-generating-functions

> For any $0<p<1$ and $r$ a positive integer, the probability function
>   $$f(x)={{r+x-1}\choose{x}}p^r(1-p)^x \ \ \ \ \ \ x=0,1,2...$$
>   defines a random variable $X$.

I have computed the mgf of the above distribution to be $$m_X(u)=\Big(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^u)}\Big)^r \ \ \ \ \ \ \ u<\text{ln}((1-p)^{-1})$$

> Define a new random variable by $\ Y=2pX\ $. Write down the mgf $m_Y(u)$ of $Y$ and show that $$\lim_{p\to 0} m_Y(u)=\Big(\frac{1}{1-2u}\Big)^r$$

I am unsure of how to solve this, but here is my attempt.

\begin{align*}
m_Y(u)&=\mathbb{E}(e^{uY})\\
&=\mathbb{E}(e^{2pXu})\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} e^{2pxu}{{r+x-1}\choose{x}}p^r(1-p)^x\\
&=\frac{p^r}{(1-(1-p)e^{2pu})^r} \sum_{x=0}^\infty \binom{r+x-1}{x} (1 - (1-p)e^{2pu})^r ((1-p)e^{2pu})^x \\
&=\frac{p^r}{(1-(1-p)e^{2pu})^r}
\end{align*}
But clearly in my response, $$\lim_{p\to 0} m_Y(u)\neq\Big(\frac{1}{1-2u}\Big)^r$$
I'm confident there's an error in my logic, but I don't know where.

Comment: You have that limit for $p \to 0$

Comment: Apologies, I have this. It is indeed $p\rightarrow 0$

Comment: taylorexpand $e^{2pu} = 1 + 2pu + O(p^2)$ and you can deduce the limit

Comment: I do not see how this will get the answer, as you arrive at $\ m_Y(u)=\mathbb{E}(1)$.

Comment: $1-(1-p)(1+2pu + O(p^2)) = p - 2pu + O(p^2)=p(1-2u + O(p)) $and simplify

Comment: why would you need that. You have a p factor both above and below the fraction. So they cancel algebraically.

Comment: Is it valid to use L'Hopital's rule om $m_Y(u)$? e.g. $$\lim_{p\to 0} m_Y(u)=\lim_{p\to 0} \Bigg(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^{2pu}}\Bigg)^r=\lim_{p\to 0} \Bigg(\frac{1}{-2ue^{2pu}+2pue^{2pu}+e^{2pu}}\Bigg)^r= \Bigg(\frac{1}{1-2u}\Bigg)^r$$

Comment: I just don't understand your method. Would you be able to write it up?

Comment: according to your derivation you have $e^{2pu}$ not $e^u$

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Typo has been fixed.

Comment: yes you can do it that way

Comment: Is there a reason why we can ignore the exponent ($r$)?

Comment: $f(z) =z^k$ is continuous hence $a_n \to a$ implies $f(a_n) \to  f(a)$

Comment: If you're able, I'd enjoy seeing your solution. I shall mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L'Hoptal's rule works fine. But one can use teh taylor expansion as well as in, for small $p$ we can use the taylor expansion of $e^x$ and assume $2u \neq 1$, we get,
$$
\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^{2pu}} = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)(1+2pu + O(p^2))} = \frac{p}{1-1+p-2pu + 2up^2 + O(p^2)}
$$ Summing things up and factor a $p$ leads to
$$
\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^{2pu}} =\frac{p}{p(1-2u+O(p))} = \frac{1}{1-2u+O(p)}\to\frac{1}{1-2u}
$$ continuity of $f(z) = z^k$ now gives the result.